# Aria-selected attribute for row selection in a grid

Tags: accessibility, wai-aria, screen-readers, jaws-screen-reader

`aria-selected` attribute is used to indicate that a row in a grid is selected, When I use the jaws keys to navigate to selected row in the grid, its not being read as selected. Any clue/suggestion to make this work right?

I am using the latest FF and Jaws 12

Answer (score 0):

According to [this link](http://www.paciellogroup.com/blog/2010/10/jaws-support-for-aria/) Jaws should support this. See the table in the "ARIA States" section. Its possible Firefox may not support the selected attribute, have you tested with the latest version of Internet Explorer? Unfortunately I have not found an exhaustive comparison of what Aria features are supported across all browsers so I would recommend testing with both Firefox and Internet explorer. You may also want to give [NVDA](http://www.nvda-project.org/) a try as a screen reader since it may support some ARIA features Jaws won't.

Comment: Used latest IE and NVDA nothing worked. But found a workaround that by having aria-selected on each cell(td) says it has selected. User would be little confused, but if this is documented it should be fine.

Comment: Likely the issue here is that JAWS - and perhaps NVDA also - don't really expose rows to the user. There's a table, and there's cells that you can navigate by direction (up, down, left, right), but as a user, you're not really aware of rows as distinct objects. They existing in the DOM, but that's it. While JAWS does have keys to navigate by row, it's really navigating its own internal model of the table, rather than traversing the HTML DOM directly - the clue here is that it also has keys to navigate by columns, which aren't HTML DOM elements.

Comment: (Also, sometimes JAWS can be picky about what elements it supports certain properties on - it may only check certain states on certain element types, so even though JAWS may say it supports something, that doesn't always mean it supports it *everywhere*.)